# i am getting error "Cannot resolve class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout" in android studio

Tags: android

I am getting an error in Cannot resolve class android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout while importing DrawerLayout

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id ="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width ="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows = "true"
    tools:openDrawer = "start">


    <include
        layout= "@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android.id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows = "true"
        app:menu = "@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android studio is upgraded now, make sure you have imported correct version of DrawerLayout. `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`

I think, it should be import `androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout` as of now.